# self join after an inner join

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I am finding what cities have the same name in different states. The city name and state name are in seperate tables (cities and states) and can be inner joined over a seperate common column.

```
select c1.city, c1.state, c2.city, c2.state 
from cities 
inner join states on cities.commonid = states.commonid
```

After inner joining i need to self join to perform a function as follows

```
select c1.city, c1.state, c2.city, c2.state
from *joined table* c1 join
     *joined table* c2
     on c1.city = c2.city and c1.state <> c2.state
```

i am wondering how i can self join a table that is the result of another join in the same query
output will be like this

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| city1    | state1|city2   |state2  |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| x        | melb  | x      | syd    |
| y        | bris  | y      | ACT    |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Your query looks correct.  What is the problem, and can you add sample data which explains what you want here?

Comment: Please supply sample data and output to demonstrate your problem [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the table `cities` has a column like `state_id` that references a column `state_id` in the table `states` (change the names to the actual names of the columns).
First do a self join for `cities` with the conditions:

```
c1.city = c2.city AND c1.state_id < c2.state_id
```

The `<` operator makes sure that each pair of cities wil be returned only once.
Then join 2 copies of `states`, because each of them will be used to get the name of the state for each of the 2 cities:

```
SELECT c1.city city1, s1.state state1,
       c2.city city2, s2.state state2
FROM cities c1 
INNER JOIN cities c2 ON c1.city = c2.city AND c1.state_id < c2.state_id
INNER JOIN states s1 ON s1.state_id = c1.state_id
INNER JOIN states s2 ON s2.state_id = c2.state_id
ORDER BY city1
```

Comment: yep; the < operator just solved my problem ~ thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do select of your inner join query and give it alias.

Then it will become something like below...

```
Select c.city,c.state from
(Select City,state from cities inner join states where cities.id = states.id) as c
```

---

Now make a self join for c.

Comment: Why not put in the whole solution (having updated the join)?

Comment: attempting to self join c in this situation returns an error `relation "c" does not exist
LINE 5:  join c c2 on c.city = c2.city and c.state <> c2.state`

Comment: Need to see the full query; sample data (not just results) would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a pre-query of all cities that have more than one state.  Then join to the states table to see which states they are encountered.

```
    select
          Duplicates.city,
          s.state
       from
          ( select c1.city
               from cities c1
               group by c1.city
               having count(*) > 1 ) Duplicates
             JOIN cities c2
                on Duplicates.city = c2.city
                JOIN states s
                   on c2.commonid = s.commonid
      order by
         Duplicates.city,
         s.state
```

By NOT trying to do cross-tab of just two city/states, you would get a single list.  If one city name exists in 5 states, how would you plan on showing that.  This way you would see all alphabetized.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a CTE:

```
with cs as (
      select c.name as city_name, s.name as state_name
      from cities c join
           states s
           on c.commonid = s.commonid
     )
select cs1.*, cs2.*
from cs cs1 join
     cs cs2
     on cs1.name = cs2.name and cs1.state <> cs2.state;
```